# File copying from jump server to multiple server

Tags: file-sharing, transfer

Does someone have a script which can help me to copy a file from jump server `/tmp`  directory to multiple servers' `/tmp` directory in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **scp** to copy the file from a host to different one.
More information about **scp** can be found at: [scp Example Syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)